# Correctness of Java code

Tags: methods, coding-style, correctness

my question is *all about to write nice and clean Java code*.
Let's say that I have this method:

```
public static int getRealPosY() {
    realPosY = (matrix.length -1) - pos.getPosY();
    return realPosY;
}
```

and I call:

```
matrix[posX][getRealPosY()] = 1;
```

Is this nice and clean for you?? I know that my method return me an Int but...I don't know why....to call a method like this seems "weird" for me. I just want to learn the right way to write this....

I can also write:

```
int y = getRealPosY();
matrix[posX][y] = 1;
```

But like this seems to have a useless access to a variable.

Or I can use the same variable "private static int realPosY;":

```
realPosY = getRealPosY();
matrix[posX][realPosY] = 1;
```

But, again, it seems weird to use exactly the same variable of the get method.

I'm quite new of Java so of course I'm a bit confuse. BTW if someone want to teach me it would be great. Thank you very much.

Comment: The fact that getRealPosY() actually goes and does a calculation and sets a global variable is a "side effect" - we don't like side effects!

Comment: @John3136 it looks very intentional, not a side effect.. what do you mean by side effect. He could've done it so it just did that and doesn't return a value. I suppose returning a value is a more preferred design pattern but the other way works too. It's kind of done two design patterns there..

Comment: The method is "get something", not "calculate something set a global variable and then return it" - sure it's ok in a small learning app, but in "real code" it's a side effect and a pain to debug / maintain. In this case, a better solution may be `calculateRealPosY() { realPosY = (matrix.length -1) - pos.getPosY(); }` and just use `realPosY` directly in the code.

Comment: @John3136 that is more than intentional. I use getRealPosY() a lot in my code because I simply need it. And It looked better for me to create a method (also just for calculation) to do that. For me this is so much better than write every time the calculation.....

Comment: As I said, fine for a school project, but at anywhere I've ever worked as a developer, it wouldn't pass a code review because of the glaring side effect. If you really don't want to modify, change the name `calculateAndGet...` for example. You asked for advice...

Comment: @John3136 Yeah in fact that's totally fine thanks :). So you mean that I can write: 'public static int calculateRealPosY() {
    realPosY = (matrix.length -1) - pos.getPosY();
    return realPosY;
}' and then use: 'matrix[posX][calculateRealPosY()] = 1;' ???

Comment: Yes, that is valid, and I think it's better than "get with a side effect"

Comment: @John3136 Thank you very much!! Your approah looks good. Can you answer my question?? So I can give you the right answer!

Comment: Your second version of the call is the best.  It's good to have things like index values "exposed" so that you can see their values while debugging.  Don't worry about creating another local variable -- they are literally free in Java -- don't "cost" anything.

Comment: @John3136 that is a good point, that relative to the name of the method, the functionality is incorrect and includes a side correct. As the name implies it's a getter. He's kind of setting a variable as a second way to  get a variablr, a kind of update method in addition to his get/return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion

```
public static int getRealPosY() {
    realPosY = (matrix.length -1) - pos.getPosY();
    return realPosY;
}
```

Is bad because it it isn't just getting some value, it has a side effect of changing the value of the global variable `realPosY`. This is ok in your own small program, but if you are working with other people (or on a big code base), then it can make the code harder to debug and maintain.

The "normal" solution is probably one `calculateRealPosY()` method that just sets the global, and then use the global directly (we won't open the can-o-worms about why you have globals in the first place ;-)

If it really does make your calling code easier, then `calculateRealPosY()` can return the new value of `realPosY` - it's still slightly ambiguous, but it's a lot better than completely hidden side effects in a getter!

Comment: Thanks! ;) .For me your answer is useful.

Answer (score -1):

Matrix is a 2D array. An array of an array.  Obviously getRealPosY() returns an int, the method is of type int.

With this code you point out that it's a useless access to a variable.. right. Unless you find it easier to read, in which case it has a use for you. Sometimes if code is easier even for a pro to read, then it has a use even if it's less concise.

```
int y = getRealPosY();
matrix[posX][y] = 1;
```

You give the example of

```
realPosY = getRealPosY();
matrix[posX][realPosY] = 1;
```

Well, yeah if it's public static int realPosY, that is pointless to even get the value you could just say  `getRealPosY();`  instead of realPosY=getRealPosY();
(Been a while since I did java but i'm sure it accepts calling a function like a procedure)

It also seems like a funny design pattern (what you call "weird"), to have a function(returning a value) also set a variable outside of it. Often one chooses a function so as to be (what one lecturer I know,  called) 'constructive' rather than 'destructive' i.e. return a new value rather changing the existing one.

And if realPosY was declared or also declared, locally in the function, then the function wouldn't be setting the one outside, and then it'd be such a waste to say realPosY=getrealPosY())  because realPosY won't yet have the value, but still you can put the function call in the [] of the array.